# Change height of UIPopoverController, to height of UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

In my app there is the need for a popover element, that displays the full description.

There is a normal `UITextView` in the `UIViewController` that displays the first 4 lines of the description. Now when the user clicks on that description the full description must be displayed. This will be done with the popover control recently introduced for the iPhone.

At the moment everything works, except for the fact that I want the popover to have a height that is exactly the height of the string in the `UITextView` in the `DescriptionPopupViewController`. This way if the description is longer, it will automatically make the popover higher.

The following code is called when the user clicks the `UITextView`:

```
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    if textView == descriptionTextView {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main-alternative", bundle: nil)
        let popoverController = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("descriptionControllerID") as! DescriptionPopupViewController
        popoverController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        popoverController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = popoverController;
        popoverController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = descriptionTextView
        popoverController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = descriptionTextView.frame
        popoverController.descriptionText = currentObject?["description"] as! String

        if let frameHeight = popoverController.textView?.frame.height {
            popoverController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, frameHeight)
        }

        self.presentViewController(popoverController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    return false
}
```

So the `preferredContentSize` should get the height of the enclosed `UITextView` in the `DescriptionPopupViewController`. However when I try to do something like this it won't work:

I think because the frameHeight is `nil`

Comment: But is entering or not inside your `if` statement in debug time?

Answer (score 0):

When the `UIViewController` is created its view hierarchy may not (and so all subviews, properties will still be `nil`), for optimization reasons it may not be loaded. You need to the access controller's `view` to force it to load its view hierarchy. So you need to update you code like the following:

```
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool {

   if textView == descriptionTextView {
       let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main-alternative", bundle: nil)
       let popoverController = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("descriptionControllerID") as! DescriptionPopupViewController

       popoverController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
       popoverController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = popoverController;
       popoverController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = descriptionTextView
       popoverController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = descriptionTextView.frame

       // forces to load its view hierarchy
       var view = popoverController.view 
       popoverController.descriptionText = currentObject?["description"] as! String

       if let frameHeight = popoverController.textView?.frame.height {
           popoverController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, frameHeight)
       }

       self.presentViewController(popoverController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }

   return false
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Hi Victor, thanks for your suggestion. I understand now the initialising of the view was missing (it was late) and this fixes the fact that I can get the height of the view. However the issue of the height remains, as apparently `popoverController.textView?.frame.height` does not returns the correct height. The `ViewController` is setup with AutoLayout, and only has a `UITextView` with top, left, right constraints, and `scrolling` is disabled. So I expected a view as high as the `UITextView`, right?